# all pdfs generating correctly using http handler , except for one in web application

Tags: asp.net, webforms, httphandler

I am trying to generate pdf on clicking on url for different invoices on front end,  using httphandler in asp.net web forms in the back end. The pdf generates well for all the invoices except for one, ON LIVE environment.
It opens a dialog box saying:
"Adobe Reader could not open '_XYZ__.pdf' because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)"

While , when I try to replicate the same on my Dev / test enviroment , all the pdfs generate properly for all the invoices.

Hence, I am unable to debug the issue on Live. How do I solve it and what could be the reason. Please guide.
Thanks

Comment: Try Writing the PDF-data to disk on your server and have a look at the file, try opening it in Adobe Reader and if that doesn't succeed, try opening it in a text editor and see if there's something non-pdf about it.

Comment: Dont really understand, your way of analysing the pdf..because the same pdf, as i had mentioned, is opening correctly on dev environment/locally hosted application.

Comment: Well, since you get a damaged or corrupt PDF file from your prod Environment, by process of elimination I'd save whatever data is created on the prod. server as a .pdf file and download it via FTP or similar and see how the file looks, what has been corrupted etc and then go back to my code and see if there was something there that could be the culprit. It's all about trying to pinpoint the issue, since it works in the dev. environment and the nature of the problem I'd start by doing what I said and take it from there.